# Retrieve rows when values of one column changes at least once for another column value

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like below in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (val1 VARCHAR(10), val2 VARCHAR(10) )

INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES ('x', 'a'), ('x', 'a'), ('p', 'b'), ('y', 'a'), ('p', 'b');

val1  |  val2
------+-------
x     |   a
x     |   a
p     |   b
y     |   a
p     |   b
```

The result should be rows of a (of val2) only as value of a in val1 changes to y at least once. But the rows of val2.b should be ignored in the result as its value in val1 does not change.

```
val1  |  val2
------+------
x     |   a
x     |   a
y     |   a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
select t.*
from @tbl t
INNER JOIN (    select  t2.val2
                from @tbl t2
                group by t2.val2 
                having min(t2.val1) <> max(t2.val1)
            ) AS tt ON tt.val2 = t.val2
```

Answer (score 2):

I have finally end up using like below.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM @tbl t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT t2.val2
    FROM @tbl t2
    WHERE t.val2 = t2.val2
    GROUP BY t2.val2
    HAVING min(t2.val1) <> max(t2.val1)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
select t.*
from @tbl t
where t.val2 = (select t2.val2
                from @tbl t2
                group by t2.val2 
                having min(t2.val1) <> max(t2.val1)
               );
```

Comment: It returns all the rows.

Comment: Changing min(t2.val1) <> max(t2.val2) to min(t2.val1) <> max(t2.val1) and = to in works.

Comment: @bill . . . Yes, that would be correct.  That was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM @tbl
WHERE val2 IN
(
    SELECT
        Z.val2
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY val2 Order BY Val2) AS PartNo
        FROM     
        (
            SELECT 
                *   
            FROM @tbl 
            GROUP BY val1,val2
        )X
    )Z WHERE Z.PartNo>1
)
```